# UITableView Content Size Smaller than Expected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, contentsize

I have a UIScrollView with a UITableView inside. I have disabled scrolling on the table view. I am using the following code to keep the UITableView's height to the height of it's content.

```
override func updateViewConstraints() {
        self.editView!.editTblHeightCnst.constant = self.editView!.editTbl.contentSize.height + self.editView!.editTbl.contentInset.top + self.editView!.editTbl.contentInset.bottom + self.editView!.editTbl.contentOffset.y
        super.updateViewConstraints()
    }
```

However, the content size I'm getting there is too small. If I add a couple hundered or less to the content size, it works. Why is my content size not what I'm expecting and how do I fix this?

Comment: uitableview is subclass of scrollview , so why u adding tableview on scrollview , just use tableview and no need to maintain its height it will grow automatically based on content size

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari I can't do that. In this case, I need a few views, then a table view with it's height fit to it's content, all inside a scroll view.

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution, write this before doing all your work  :

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 0;
```

> In iOS 11, table views use estimated heights by default. This means
>   that the contentSize is just as estimated value initially. If you need
>   to use the contentSize, you’ll want to disable estimated heights by
>   setting the 3 estimated height properties to zero:
>   tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 0
>   tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 0
>   tableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 0

source : https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/81895